# facebook like - image display and description

Tags: facebook

i have some difficulties with the new Facebook like feature. usually, each one of my [blog](http://yeho.co.il) post has an image in it. when i use the facebook share feature everything is going well: it lets me choose as a thumbnail between the images embedded in my post and in the description it shows the entire first paragraph (or at least most of it).

recently i've added the new [facebook like](http://mashable.com/2011/02/27/facebook-like-button-takes-over-share-button-functionality/) feature to my blog but i can't make it behave like the share feature - when i like a post it doesn't use the post embedded image as a thumbnail. i managed to to make it display a default thumbnail by inserting this to header.php -

```
<meta property="og:tag name" content="tag value"/>
```

however, this is is only a partial solution. is there a way to make it use the post image as a thumbnail?

in addition to the thumbnail issue, the like shown on my news feed doesn't grab the first paragraph as a description but only the 85 characters of it. is there a way to make it show the whole paragraph or at least more characters?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use my plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like-thumbnail/ or the code manually in your functions.php that I have here on my post with explanation - http://blog.ashfame.com/2011/02/wordpress-plugin-fix-facebook-like-thumbnail/

**Edit:** It will use the first image of your post. Also Facebook will refresh all of your pages in max 24hours, so if you need to force refresh a page manually, try the linter tool - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

**Edit:** Regarding the description, if you have a meta named description which you should, because that way you can tell search engines the description of the current page, Facebook will pick that up. Its good both ways, as this is the text people will see below title both on search engines, and on Facebook.

Comment: Ashfame, thank you, the plugin did the trick.

as for the meta named description - which meta description you mean?

is it the "og:description"?

i can insert it to header.php but if i understand correctly, that means that all my posts will have the same description. this is not what i as i want description, that is, to show the first paragraph of the post.

Comment: Use Yoast SEO plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/